# How to Fix this Cordova & Ionic Issue

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I am getting this Error While installing Cordova using NPM (node JS).

Please see the following Image

[image]

Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your npm registry URL is incorrect (`EAI_AGAIN` is a DNS lookup error).

The default URL is: `https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Thus:

- either do not call `npm config set` at all, so as to stick with the the default
- or, if for some reason you do need to set the URL explicitly, use:
  `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: Hello , if i am not using "npm config set"   than it's showing this error

Comment: Please see this Image Url , now i am getting this error when i am not at all calling  "npm config set " means i am stick to the default .                                                     http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob5sU.png

Comment: Hello ,Please check the Image Url and Confirm that both Cordova and Ionic is Installed correctly or not .                                                                           http://i.stack.imgur.com/94pEH.png                                please confirm .....